# Database representation of a timeline

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Say I have a timeline which displays 2 kinds of events:

1. A patient has visited a clinic. Such an event references to the patient and the clinic.
2. A patient has uploaded a photo. Such an event references to the patient and the photo.

So I have a few underlying tables here: `patients`, `clinics`, `photos`.
I also have a few timeline tables: `timeline_visit`, `timeline_photo`.

The question is am I forced to use separate tables for every timeline event type and then use `UNION` to build a complete timeline or there are some other techniques that I don't know about (to store all the possible events in one table)?
The tables `timeline_visit` and `timeline_photo` have common and differing fields and keys as you can see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would create a table called `events` which contains four columns:

**events**

```
patient_id int
id int
event_date timestamp
event_type int
```

Each entry would represent one patient event at one point in time.  It could be a clinic visit or an upload of a photo.  There would be two tables for visits and photos:

**visits**

```
id int
event_id int
doctor_id int
decimal (10, 2) cost
double length_of_visit
```

**uploads**

```
id int
event_id int
image_id int
image_content blob
```

Now when you want to generate a timeline of events you can accomplish it by querying a single table:

```
SELECT *
FROM events
WHERE event_date BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 HOUR)
```

The above query would give you a timeline for the last 3 hours.  If you want details about each event in the query, then you might have to do a clever `UNION` query, because the columns will not be the same for each event.

Comment: Thanks man, your approach seems to be more eloquent and reasonable. The timeline can be displayed by pulling it just from the main table and fetching concrete events' information from the corresponding tables when needed.